# How to detect specific (timeout) errors for THTTPReqResp SOAP requests?

Tags: delphi, error-handling, soap-client, wininet, delphi-10.3-rio

In Delphi Tokyo 10.2.x a `ESOAPHTTPException` was an Exception descendant with a StatusCode property set in the creator:

```
ESOAPHTTPException = class(Exception)
private
  FStatusCode: Integer;
public
{$IF CompilerVersion <= 15.0}
  constructor Create(const Msg: string; SCode: Integer = 0);
{$ELSE}
  constructor Create(const Msg: string; SCode: Integer = 0; Dummy: Integer = 0);
{$IFEND}
  constructor CreateFmt(const Msg: string; const Args: array of const; SCode: Integer = 0; Dummy: Integer = 0);

  property StatusCode: Integer read FStatusCode write FStatusCode;
end;
```

I could detect *specific* errors by looking at the StatusCode value:

```
// WinINet error codes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.serviceerror%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx
if (E is ESOAPHTTPException) and (ESOAPHTTPException(E).StatusCode = ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT) then
begin
```

We use `THTTPReqResp`. In Tokyo `THTTPReqResp` error handling code called `HandleWinInetError(GetLastError,` , which tested for some specific errors and for the others called `THTTPReqResp.RaiseCheck`, which then called `raise ESOAPHTTPException.CreateFmt('` - all passing the GetLastError value. That's how it ended up in the StatusCode property.

But now in Delphi Rio 10.3.1 `ESOAPHTTPException = ENetException;` and `ENetException = class(Exception);` and there no longer is a StatusCode.
`HandleWinInetError` is gone.

Looking though `THTTPReqResp` or `THTTPReqRespHelper = class helper for THTTPReqResp` I see that e.g. the `THTTPReqResp.Execute` raises the `ESOAPHTTPException`:

```
on Ex: ESOAPHTTPException do
begin
  if not CanRetry or not IsErrorStatusCode(HTTPResponse.StatusCode) then
    raise;
    ...
end;
```

... but at that moment `HTTPResponse.StatusCode` gets lost (`HTTPResponse` is  a local var in the method).

Other than hacking the Delphi code to intercept this value (e.g. by 're-creating' a ESOAPHTTPException descendant like in Delphi Tokyo),
does anyone see another way to detect specific errors (in my case the `ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT`)?
Did I overlook something?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666531/how-to-get-at-response-headers-from-thttpreqresp