# How to get at response headers from THTTPReqResp?

Tags: http, delphi, http-headers, delphi-10.3-rio

I have some old code using `THTTPReqResp`, this calls `Execute` for SOAP requests against Exchange Web Services.
I'm modifying it to (also) use OAuth login. This works fine, but I'm having trouble detecting when an access token has expired.

In a test app using a `TipwHTTP` component from nSoftware IP*Works I can go through the response headers to detect the one indicating an expired token:

```
with ipwHTTP do
  try
     PostData := ABody;
     Post(cBaseURL);
  except
      on e:Exception do
      begin
         // A special header is returned when the token has expired:
         //      Header x-ms-diagnostics: 2000002;reason="The token has expired.";error_category="invalid_lifetime"
         for l := 0 to ParsedHeaders.Count-1 do
            if (Pos('x-ms-diagnostics',ParsedHeaders[l].Field) <> 0)
            and (Pos('2000002',ParsedHeaders[l].Value) <> 0) then
            begin
               FTokenExpired := true;
               Break;
            end;
         ...   
      end;
  end;
```

**Where/how can I access the headers when using `THTTPReqResp` or `THTTPReqResp.HTTP`?**

That component contains a `HTTP` property of type `THTTPClient` but I'm getting nowhere with that.
The documentation [Using an HTTP Client](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_an_HTTP_Client#Handling_an_HTTP_Response) states that `THTTPClient` has 
[OnRequestError](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPRequest.OnRequestError) and [OnRequestcompleted](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPRequest.OnRequestCompleted) events but those are nowhere to be found in the code for `THTTPClient` or its class helper.
The documentation for these events refer to `System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPRequest` not `System.Net.THTTPClient`, *and* there is no `HttpClientComponent` in `System.Net`.

Notes:

- This is Delphi 10.3.1 Rio; in 10.3 significant code changes were made to `THTTPReqResp`.
- `System.Net.HttpClientComponent` has a `TNetHTTPClient` with those two events, and a comment says it's a *Component to Manage an HTTPClient*, but that code does not seem to be linked in (i.e. `HttpClientComponent` is never used)
- What may be related is that there is a `TNetHTTPClient` in the component palette (and `TNetHTTPRequest`, those are the only two in the Net folder), but not a `THTTPClient`. This seems to indicate that `THTTPClient` is only meant to be used 'under the hood'. `TNetHTTPClient` also has a HTTP (`THTTPClient`) property, like `THTTPReqResp`, but there is no inheritance between the two.

Comment: What is the status code, when the token expires?

Comment: @Peter It's a 401, so I can't distinguish from other errors based on that.

Comment: I was just trying to identify whether global `OnHttpError` handler is applicable in your scenario. This is when server returns non-2xx status code - see the answer.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836189/how-to-detect-specific-timeout-errors-for-thttpreqresp-soap-requests

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out `THTTPReqResp` underwent shotgun surgery in Delphi 10.3. Originally it was using WinINet on Windows and Indy on Linux under the hood, but they changed it to `THTTPClient` (to support mobile platforms, I guess).

In this new implementation none of `THTTPReqResp` methods (`Get`, `Execute`) and events (`OnBeforePost`, `OnReceivingData`) expose `Request` or `Response` objects.

There, however, is a chance to gain access to `Response` object via global `OnHttpError` handler, if server responds with an error HTTP status code (>= 300). Use procedure `Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans.SetOnHttpError` to install the global handler. It has `HTTPResponse: IHTTPResponse` as its second parameter, which lets you inspect returned headers. If the server responds with 1xx or 2xx status then you're out of luck and should consider implementing custom `THTTPReqResp` descendant or migrating to more appropriate HTTP client implementation (e.g. `THTTPClient` directly, or similar).

```
{ assuming HTTPReqResp1: THTTPReqResp is a component on TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetOnHttpError(HTTPReqRespError);
end;

procedure TForm1.HTTPReqRespError(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp;
  const HTTPResponse: IHTTPResponse; const Error: ESOAPHTTPException;
  var Action: TSOAPHttpErrorAction);
begin
  if (HTTPReqResp = HTTPReqResp1) and StartsText('2000002', HTTPResponse.HeaderValue['x-ms-diagnostics']) then
  begin
    FTokenExpired := True;
    Action := TSOAPHttpErrorAction.heaAbort; { or whatever }
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTokenExpired := False;
  try
    { ... }
    { HTTPReqResp1.Get or HTTPReqResp1.Execute or whatever }
    { ... }
  except
    if not FTokenExpired then
      raise;
    { handle token expiration here  }
  end;
end;
```

In my personal opinion this is pretty ugly way to handle such cases and I just can't understand why they introduced global handler in **new** code, which affects all instances of `THTTPReqResp`. I'm not impressed with this new design at all.

*Eagle eye*: Have you noticed character case inconsistency between `THTTPReqResp` (`THTTPClient`, `ESOAPHTTPException`) and `SetOnHttpError` (`TSOAPHttpErrorEvent`, `TSOAPHttpErrorAction`)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's ugly. Either I will try this or rewrite everything to use a TNetHTTPClient (or better, a TipwHTTP since we have that anyway) instead of THTTPReqResp. But that's quite a lot of work because I then have to collect all return data and assemble it into an XML file. Well.

Comment: Nice eagle eye, MacGyver. Better than my *hhtp* or *htpp* typos ;-)

Comment: Update: I have indeed rewritten the code to replace THTTPReqResp with TipwHTTP. [Beware of this pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707734/parameter-name-key-cannot-be-null-for-ews-soap-updateitem-call)